# Payfort Payment Gateway Prodution Flow Fluctuations

Tags: typescript, payfort

I've got stuck in the production roadmap, i have followed the custom page integration, and we have followed the documentation respectively!

I'm facing issues of completion of flows on actual cards, I have tested production flow on test cards, but it didn't work respectively with real cards!

1. Fluctuations occur, while getting a success response, but the amount wasn't deducted from the account!
2. Got error such as 'Merchant reference already exists',
3. Got error such as 'Failed to execute service'

docs followed:

- https://paymentservices-reference.payfort.com/docs/api/build/index.html#custom-merchant-page-integration

APIs followed:

- https://checkout.PayFort.com/FortAPI/paymentPage
- https://paymentservices.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentApi

Account has been setup to production from payfort already, merchant account, and access has been updated respectively!

The flow is working completely fine on test cards, but not in actual cards!

The programming language is TypeScript (NodeJS)

Sandbox to production movement, Tested the flow on sandbox, and moved credentials everything from sandbox to production!

Sandbox:

- https://sbcheckout.PayFort.com/FortAPI/paymentPage
- https://sbpaymentservices.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentApi

Production:

- https://checkout.PayFort.com/FortAPI/paymentPage
- https://paymentservices.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentApi

Comment: Without any code it will be difficult to help you, but first please check that the url is correct, second check that there is not a constant variable like .PROD or .DEV

Comment: for example checking the doc there is a .PRODUCTION and .TEST property or PayFortEnviromentSandBox or PayFortEnviromentProduction ...

Comment: @LilianBideau, thanks for the feedback, just like i have mentioned above, between sanbox and production, its only matter of credentials and endpoints changes, i have changed them respectively, i have also checked this checked and unchecked for sandbox to production thing, seems everything okay!